# |Solved| How to store JSX in variable in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have a Requirement in which i need to store JSX/TSX
For Example:
`<div>Hello {name} </div>`

in a variable, like this:
`const Ele = <><div>Hello {name} </div></>`
to export for another component in React.

Well in normal Javascript it works fines! Everything.

But Problem is TypeScript isn't allowing me to store this even after declaring it to `varName:any`

(NOTE: For my requirement creating a React Functional Component won't Work!!! It must be normal variable in .ts file)

If anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance! ;)

I tried it with :any and different JSX matching types which is provided by default, but no luck :(

Comment: Rather than changing title to solved, you can accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You want a React component, which is a function that returns JSX:

```js
const Ele = () => <><div>Hello {name} </div></>;
```

Comment: Hey this actually works, but I also find another solution that :JSX.Element and :React.ReactNode both types works fine, in any case thank you so so much for your effort!

Comment: Note that usage of a react component is slightly different (and possibly more idiomatic!)

Comment: "to export for another component in React." sounded like it was being exported from a file? React nodes exist only when rendering, which is not the same as during static export. We would need to see more code what is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `React.ReactNode` type for your React node element

```typescript
const name: React.ReactNode = Ele
```

Comment: Yes I just found out that :JSX.Element and :React.ReactNode both types works fine, i really thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Take into account `React.ReactNode` in addition to `JSX.Element` includes all other possible node types: `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`. And in general it is more useful